# How to draw real time chart like AED (defibrillator) display using qwt

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qwt

I can draw real time chart using QwtPlotCurve::drawSeries function and QwtSamplingThread. Once the chart is drawn to end of x axis displayed, i want to continue drawing the chart from left to right again after the existing one is erased but i want to leave the existing one until continuous one takes its area. 
This mean erasing and drawing happen at the same time (of course not for the first drawing where nothing to erase).

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: I don't know if qwt supports such a drawing mode, but at any rate, you could implement it yourself easily. I recently posted a trivial example how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708497/ecg-like-waveform-painting-using-qpainter/33709570#33709570

Comment: @ddriver Thanks alot ddriver. it helped me so much. thanks again!